# How can I transform the double-character が into the single-character が?

Tags: discussion

These two characters are different: が and が.

The first one is actually two characters. If I try to delete it with backspace, it will first delete the dakuten, leaving behind the か。I need to press backspace again to delete it completely.

The second is just one character and will be deleted by backspacing once.

You can test this yourself by copying and pasting on a text editor.

I would like to transform the first kind of character into the second so a learning app I use can parse it properly. Is there a way to do this?

Note: In this post, the double-character が is rendered as two characters. However, when I type the double-character が, I see it as just one character on my Mac. If in reality, the double-character が is just two characters that are put together by my Mac, then my question still stands. How do I turn these two characters into one?

Note2: I get these characters from copying Japanese from a PDF file.

Comment: Try this: https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/transform.jsp?a=Any-NFC, explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick!

Comment: Separately, your use case isn't very clear.  Why are you copying the two-codepoint version?  That is a rather rare combination -- most everyone just uses the single-codepoint が character.  Can you just copy the single-codepoint が character from your PDF file?  Also, do you have access to an input method editor (IME)?  Mac OS comes with a good IME for Japanese.  If you enable that, you can generate a が by simply typing **ga**.

Comment: Interestingly, on my screen, the two-char version renders as a normal か but adds the dakuten to the following English word: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JifF3.png